# Characterizing direct sum of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose $M$ is an $R$-module (for a commutative ring $R$ with $1$) and that $(M_i)_{i\in I}$ is a collection of $R$-submodules of $M$. The inclusion maps $j_i:M_i\rightarrow M$ determine an $R$ module homomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(M,N)\rightarrow\prod_{i\in I}\operatorname{Hom}(M_i,N)$ given by $\varphi\mapsto (\varphi\circ j_i)_{i\in I}$, where $N$ is any arbitrary $R$-module.

Suppose that this map is an isomorphism for any $N$. I'm trying to understand why this implies that $M$ is a direct sum of the $M_i$. I tried plugging in different values for $N$, such as $M$ and then mapping over the identity, but this doesn't seem to get me anywhere. Any suggestions? What am I missing?

Edit: I am looking for a reason that does not appeal to the universal property.

Comment: This should work as long as you allow N to be arbitrary (so, the map is an iso for all N)

Comment: @AndresMejia Yes, $N$ is arbitrary

Comment: Then it’s true, basically by 1) it is the universal property or 2) the product is the same as $\mathrm{Hom}(\oplus M_i,N)$ together with the Yoneda lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $\bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i = \{(m_i)_{i \in I} \in \prod_{i \in I} M_i : \{i \in I: m_i\neq0\} \textrm{ is finite}\}$ comes together with a family $\{\iota_i : M_i \to \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i\}_{i \in I}$ of canonical "inclusions" (what are they?).

So, take $N = \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i$ and $\varphi \in \operatorname{Hom}(M,N)$ the preimage of $(\iota_i)_{i \in I} \in \prod_{i \in I} \operatorname{Hom}(M_i,N)$ under your isomorphism. Prove that $\varphi$ is the inverse of the $R$-module homomorphism $\psi : N \to M$ given by $(m_i)_{i \in I} \mapsto \sum_{i \in I} m_i$.

Comment: I'm actually having trouble seeing how $\varphi$ acts on the elements of $M$. I see that we get $\varphi\circ j_i = \iota_i$,  but I'm not sure what $\varphi$ looks like on elements of $M$ that might not belong to some $M_i$. What am I missing?

Comment: In particular, I think I see that $\varphi\circ\psi$ is the identity on $N$, but I'm having trouble seeing why $\psi\circ\varphi$ is the identity on $M$. Could you clarify this?

Comment: @ponchan Note that $\psi \circ \varphi \circ j_i = \psi \circ \iota_i = j_i$ for all $i \in I$, so $\psi \circ \varphi \in \operatorname{Hom}(M,M)$ is a preimage of $(j_i)_{i \in I} \in \prod_{i \in I} (M_i,M)$ under your isomorphism. But $\operatorname{id}_M \in \operatorname{Hom}(M,M)$ is also a preimage, so...

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you meant the map is an isomorphism for all $N$, you have that $\operatorname{Hom} (\bigoplus M_i, -) \cong \operatorname{Hom} (M, -)$, where the isomorphism is a natural transformation. You can now use the Yoneda embedding and you are done (since this embedding is fully faithful).